Azure MS Bot-Framework - Webchat - Citation Dialog Pop up Modal Activation - Python
I am developing Azure OpenAI based chatbot using bot framework, but struggling to activate webchat channel citation pop up modal.
`
turn_context.send_activity(
    type="message",
    text="Hello, this is your friendly bot! How can I assist you today?",
    channel_id="emulator"
        )
`

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/84c85cfbbb2967a9906b2002e4a692afa5cad14e/packages/component/src/Attachment/Text/private/MarkdownTextContent.tsx#L56
What should I inject into send_activity for citation popup modal.
